# How to write an interceptor for react router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I Want to intercept when each route is called which is declared using react-router and append a query param to the end of it.

Reason to for this would be that there are set of query params that I need to append at the end of each route, however since I am currently working on a large code base I cannot look into each route and append it. Therefore if I can write some sought of an interceptor which is call every time a route is called and then append the query param there and pass on the request it would be ideal.

Is there such a feature in react-router ? I'm using react-router v4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way that I can think of is to "enhance" the [history](https://www.npmjs.com/package/history) object that's passed into the `Provider`... You could make an enhancer of the public methods of that object and to add that functionality there, basically you would have to "enhance" the `push` and `replace` methods. Something more or less like this:

```
function pathInterceptor(path) {
  // TODO Your logic here
  // return an enhanced path that ensures that you have the
  // query string that you need
}

function historyEnhancer(originalHistory) {
  return {
    ...originalHistory,
    push: (path, ...args) =>
      originalHistory.push(pathInterceptor(path), ...args),
    replace: (path, ...args) =>
      originalHistory.replace(pathInterceptor(path), ...args),
  };
}
```

### EDIT:

Have a look at [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-enhance-history-test-l53zj) with an example of this idea.

Comment: Thanks Josep, This looks like it might help :) I'l try it out

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own 'RouteProvider' and watch for route changes from top level
Something as follows might do the trick:

```
export const RouteParent = ({ match, history }) => {
   useEffect(() => {
       // match object changed, do something
   }, [match])

   return (
       <Switch>
       {/* actual routes here */}
       </Switch>
   )
}
```